# Assert that a Laravel Livewire component sees a flash message rather than a redirect

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-livewire

I have a Livewire sign in component which takes an email address and password. If the email/password is correct, it redirects - otherwise, it shows a flash message.

How can I test this?

- `assertSee` doesn't feel write, as I'd have to hard-code the flash message
- `assertSeeLivewire` doesn't seem to see the sign in component (even though it's the component being tested
- there doesn't appear to be a method for `assertSession` or similar to detect a flash message

Comment: Looking at the source code it does not appear to be possible to perform assertions on the session with `Livewire::test()`, but depending on how your test is setup you could call something like `$this->assertTrue(session()->has('message'))` after `Livewire::test()`

Comment: Thanks @Remul, but that's not working. Looks like it always returns `false` - possibly because Livewire isn't doing a new request for that page.

For now, I'm emitting an event (as well as setting the flash) and testing for that.